# Does IdentityServer requires certain version of TLS?

Tags: ssl, identityserver3, tls1.2

I have a setup with Identity Server, Windows provider, etc., for service token and single sign on.  All works well.  But when try switching to a different proxy server which uses TLS 1.0, the token endpoint quits working.  Also the Windows provider on the single sign on part stop working in Chrome but OK in IE.

Does Identity Server require certain level of TLS?  I know 1.0 is way too low.  But just want to double check before making the change.  Thanks

EDIT: Just figured out I can make the token service call in POSTMAN, but in code using RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync, all same parameters and values, got UnAuthorized.